# Sending SMS using MFMessageComposeViewController

Tags: swift3

I want my app to send SMS and my current code didn't work, here is the steps  follow:

```
import MessageUI
```

add the class:

`MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate`

then I used a button:

```
 @IBAction func Messages(_ sender: UIButton) {


    if MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText() == true{
        let recipients:[String] = ["1500"]
        let messageController = MFMessageComposeViewController()
        messageController.messageComposeDelegate  = self // implement delegate if you want
        messageController.recipients = recipients
        messageController.body = "Your_text"
        self.present(messageController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        func messageComposeViewController(controller: MFMessageComposeViewController,
                                          didFinishWithResult result: MessageComposeResult) {

            // Dismiss the message compose view controller.
            controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)}

    }}
```

and use the function:

```
 func messageComposeViewController(_ controller: MFMessageComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MessageComposeResult) {}
```

so what did I missed? thank you.

Comment: Why you have added `didFinishWithResult` function inside the if block? It should be class level method.

Comment: @NiravD it is outside the entire button block.

Comment: Look at your question it is look like that method `didFinishWithResult` is inside the if block of `Messages` method.

Comment: @NiravD yes yes I just saw it, would you please write the full correct syntax as an answer?

Answer (score 8):

```
@IBAction func Messages(_ sender: UIButton) {   
    if MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText() == true {
        let recipients:[String] = ["1500"]
        let messageController = MFMessageComposeViewController()
        messageController.messageComposeDelegate  = self
        messageController.recipients = recipients
        messageController.body = "Your_text"
        self.present(messageController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        //handle text messaging not available
    }
}

func messageComposeViewController(_ controller: MFMessageComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MessageComposeResult) {    
    controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: I does not send message for me